# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, linker, command

I am doing build a game on Unity this ok.
I ran a xcode project but i got an error like this

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

_GADUCreateAdLoader in GADUInterface.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add several frameworks. By the name, Import GoogleMobileAds.framework and rebuild.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: No need to do any changes to the linker flags if you have proper frameworks added. 

What external sdk your game is using?

Comment: Kindly mark this as answer if it was helpful so that other people can know.